# search array select value similar

Tags: php, arrays

I want search with array into php for preview value similar but result nothing

```
function search($array, $key, $value){
        $results = array();
        if (is_array($array)) {
            if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
                $results[] = $array;
            }
            foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key,$value));
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }    
    $arr = array(0 => array('id'=>1,'title'=>"امروز یکشنبه است",),
                 1 => array('id'=>2,'title'=>"فردا یکشنبه است"),
                 2 => array('id'=>3,'title'=>"دیروز یکشنبه بود"));  
    $matches  = search($arr, 'title', 'یکشنبه');
    foreach($matches as $key=>$_search){
        echo $_search['id'];
    }
```

result = nothing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function search($array, $key, $value){
        $results = array();
        if (is_array($array)) {
            if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == strpos($array[$key], $value) > -1) {
                $results[] = $array;
            }
            foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key,$value));
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }    
    $arr = array(0 => array('id'=>1,'title'=>"امروز یکشنبه است",),
                 1 => array('id'=>2,'title'=>"فردا یکشنبه است"),
                 2 => array('id'=>3,'title'=>"دیروز یکشنبه بود"));  
    $matches  = search($arr, 'title', 'یکشنبه');
    foreach($matches as $key=>$_search){
        echo $_search['id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array` function as follows.

```
in_array($array,  $string)
```

Output of in_array is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`یکشنبه` is a substring of you title vales but you do an equality comparison. You should do a scan instead to see if the string exists inside of the other. I.e. use strpos for the comparison

```
strpos($array[$key], $value) > -1
```